# Http proxy append in front of the actual URL | Request failed with status code 503 axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, axios

I am using axios to fetch response of one of the Api http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/actuator/health, I am successfully able to fetch its value from my React Client side code, but when I am setting express endpoint for this at server side and calling below endpoint from the browser

```

```
app.get('/health', function (req, res) {
var url = serviceUrl + '/actuator/health';
axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      const data = response.data;
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
});
```

```
then I am getting below error

Error:

Request failed with status code 503
statusText: 'DNS Fail',
host: 'proxy-gcp-central.xxxx.com',
responseUrl: 'http://proxy-gcp-central.xxxx.com/http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/actuator/health'
_currentUrl: 'http://proxy-gcp-central.xxxx.com/http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/actuator/health'

**Where   http://proxy-gcp-central.xxxx.com/   is append in front of the actual url => hence it is failing**

I am getting this issue on cloud environment, I am able to fix this issue on my local by providing proxy information along with url in axios.get function above(as on local I am using proxy server to access this URL), but on cloud we are able to access this directly without use of proxy server, so for cloud, we cannot set this proxy information in this code.

I have tried this with many other node modules like http, request, request-promise, but still I am getting the same issue.

I have also tried to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in headers as well as in app.use, but none of them resolve my issue.

Context

- axios version: *e.g.: v0.17.1*
- Environment: *e.g.: node v8.11.3, npm v6.2.0, chrome 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit), windows 7*

Comment: Your server is probably not able to connect with the remote endpoint. Depending on your host environment you should check the outbound rules in the firewall to allow for the remote host.

Comment: You can try getting a remote terminal to the cloud environment and pinging/curl the remote endpoint to verify this.

Comment: I am sorry @hazardous, not able to understand your suggestion completely. is there anything, I can do in my code that will allow to connect with this endpoint like the proxy info I have used in my local, in place of proxy can i do something else which will allow to connect with this endpoint on cloud environment

Comment: Sorry, I missed your explanation in the original question that on the cloud you are able to access the remote server directly. How did you confirm that? E.g. did you run curl to connect to it?

Comment: I tried to run this using postman and using this it is working fine there

Comment: Which cloud env is it? Sounds like a VM if you are able to run postman there.

Comment: I think so, but I am not sure, Please update me with solution, Many Thanks

Comment: I need to know which cloud are you using.

Comment: openshift with google cloud